# Odoo new API - overriding old API function field

Tags: api, overriding, odoo, openerp-8

I'm trying to override old api function field with no success.
There is this function field (`display_name`) with helper methods:

```
def _display_name_compute(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    context = dict(context or {})
    context.pop('show_address', None)
    context.pop('show_address_only', None)
    context.pop('show_email', None)
    return dict(self.name_get(cr, uid, ids, context=context))

_display_name = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: self._display_name_compute(*args, **kwargs)

_display_name_store_triggers = {
    'res.partner': (lambda self,cr,uid,ids,context=None: self.search(cr, uid, [('id','child_of',ids)], context=dict(active_test=False)),
                    ['parent_id', 'is_company', 'name'], 10)
}

    'display_name': fields.function(_display_name, type='char', string='Name', store=_display_name_store_triggers, select=True)
```

What I need to change in here, is in `display_name_store_triggers`, update with new fields that if used, would trigger this function field to compute.

If I do this in source:

```
_display_name_store_triggers = {
    'res.partner': (lambda self,cr,uid,ids,context=None: self.search(cr, uid, [('id','child_of',ids)], context=dict(active_test=False)),
                    ['parent_id', 'is_company', 'name', 'parent_root_id', 'is_branch'], 10)
}
```

Then it works how I need. But I can't seem to inherit that trigger and override on my module.

If I do this on my module:

```
from openerp.addons.base.res.res_partner import res_partner as res_partner_orig

    _display_name_store_triggers = res_partner_orig._display_name_store_triggers 
    _display_name_store_triggers = {
        'res.partner': (lambda self,cr,uid,ids,context=None: self.search(cr, uid, [('id','child_of',ids)], context=dict(active_test=False)),
                        ['parent_id', 'is_company', 'name', 'parent_root_id', 'is_branch'], 10)
    }
```

Nothing happens. `display_name` field do not compute when fields `parent_root_id` or `is_branch` are modified.

I could not find in documentation how to override old function field using new API. What is the approach?

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('parent_id','is_company','name')
def _display_name(self):
    for partner in self:
        <<operation on context... you need to check yourself>>
        <<you will have to check how name_get is called and based on  
             the return value set the value as shown below>>
        partner.display_name = <<returned value from name_get>>

display_name = fields.Char(compute="_display_name",string="Display Name")
```

Comment: I already tried similar approach. The problem with it, it does not save value in database, even if you add `store=True` in function field. It looks like it still uses old function field and ignores this implementation. Also in your example you use `api.one`, but iterate like it is multi. Shouldn't it be accessed directly from `self`? Because its one record.

Comment: Iteration on self doesn't matter, as it is a recordset. Yes I forgot to add the `store=True`. If I will get chance I will check it out. But can you tell me why do you want to implement in new api?

Comment: I reimplemented new `name_get` method that changes `display_name` if new fields (I implemented) are set (`is_branch`, `parent_root_id`). So If partner is branch and has `parent_root_id` (aka main partner), it will display name like this `Main Company / Branch Company`. The problem is, it is only updated if `name` field is changed on write, because it does not trigger update if new fields are changed. So `display_name` is not being updated when it should. If I add those fields that need to be triggered in `_display_name_store_triggers`, then it works, but only if I do it in source

Comment: This is strange, can you post your latest code here?

Comment: I posted how I modified at source code in my Question. Trying same thing in my own module do not work (if I import original res_partner class from standard module). You can see my examples on Odoo issues - https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/5112